# What's the equivalent of TEMPDATA in Webmatrix?

Tags: webmatrix

1. Fill the form with data
2. Proceed to fields' validation
3. if the validation pass, go to the a different.

In ASPNET NVC, I can put my data in Tempdata["myKey"] and recover it somewhere else.

How can I obtain the same result in WebMatrix?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a direct equivalent. You can use Session instead.